# ZF2 'unable to render template' when shifting module names in the array in app config

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Good day.
I've just started learning ZF2, replicated the Album example step-by-step, and then decided to make it a bit more interesting by adding user registration, and then make the two work together in some way, so i added a new 'Auth' module.

So, when i only had one module in the module list (aside from the Application module) in application.config.php, it was all fine, but when i added the Auth module to the list like so:

```
'modules' => array('Application', 'Album','Auth',)
```

i got the following error when trying to access any views from the album module which was working absolutely fine prior to this change:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "album/album/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

But when i changed the order in which the modules are presented in this array like so:

```
'modules' => array('Application', 'Auth','Album',)
```

not a single view (and it has only one) from the Auth module could be rendered, while the Album module was fine.

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "auth/user/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

Both of these views exist at these locations, but the renderer doesn't see them for some reason.

You can see the project's contents [here](https://github.com/AlexLucas007/test/tree/dev).

Thank you for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you copy pasted the [the view manager config for Auth `module.config.php`](https://github.com/AlexLucas007/test/blob/dev/module/Auth/config/module.config.php#L37).

This should be `auth` rather than `album` for your templates to work correctly.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'auth' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```